# Create a variable for every new input

Tags: javascript, html, oop, dom

I'm practicing OOP with JS and making a book class. When any time user enter  the details it should store the values in a new variable. I have no clue on making a new variable each time user enter the details.

HTML:

```
<input id="title" type="text" name="title" placeholder="title"><br>
<input id="isbn" type="text" name="isbn" placeholder="isbn"><br>
<input id="author" type="text" name="author" placeholder="author"><br>
<button id="add">Add field</button>

<div id="display"></div>
```

JS:

```
let title = document.getElementById('title');
let isbn = document.getElementById('isbn');
let author = document.getElementById('author');
let addBtn = document.getElementById('add');
let display = document.getElementById('display')

class Book{
    constructor(title, isbn , author){
        this.title = title;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.author = author;
    }


add.addEventListener('click' , function(){
    //console.log("Works");
    let x = `${title.value} , ${isbn.value} , ${author.value}`;
    display.append(x);
}
```

How can I store user info on a variable each time they enter details.
Thank You.

Comment: Are you thinking of using an array or object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define a global empty array.  You were missing a closing } on your class.  Inside your click function instantiate the class with new. Push the object onto the global array.  You can use JSON.stringify to convert the object to a string.

```js
var myList=[]

class Book{
    constructor(title, isbn , author){
        this.title = title;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.author = author;
    }
 }


add.addEventListener('click' , function(){

let title = document.getElementById('title');
let isbn = document.getElementById('isbn');
let author = document.getElementById('author');
let display = document.getElementById('display')

let x = new Book(title.value, isbn.value, author.value);


myList.push(x);

console.log(myList)

myDisplay = display.innerHTML + " " + JSON.stringify(x).replace(/"/g,"").replace('{','').replace('}','') + "<br>";


display.innerHTML = myDisplay;


    
})
```

```html
<input id="title" type="text" name="title" placeholder="title"><br>
<input id="isbn" type="text" name="isbn" placeholder="isbn"><br>
<input id="author" type="text" name="author" placeholder="author"><br>
<button id="add">Add field</button>

<div id="display"></div>
```